# Replace multiple similar values in a column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a data frame with deidentified information that looks like this

```
Gender    Age   Score
 Male      2      7
 Male      6      1
 Male      5      5
 Male      3      9
 Female    9      11
 Female    12      11
 Female    6      11
```

I would like to replace all the 2's with "5 years old" and all the 3's with "6 years old" and so on.

I can use this

`data$Age[data$Age ==2] <- 5 years old`

but I have data ranging from 5 years to 25 years old and to repeat that 20 times is not exactly appealing.

**I would like a function to iterate from 2 all the way to 22.**

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I assume `Age` is stored as a numeric? Do you want the variable converted to `character` to add the string "years old", or do you simple want the number 2 replaced with the number 5, etc?

Comment: Age is stored as an Int. I would like to add the string "years old" to the output.

Comment: Perhaps i need to clarify my questions. I would like the function to iterate from value 2 all the way to 22

Comment: This construction: `data$Age[data@age ==2]` is kind of weird. R has two different list accessor functions: "$" and "@". They work on different sorts of objects, so you would not generally use both on the same argument.

Comment: That was a typo. I meant to use $ twice. I will edit the original question. Apologies

Comment: @IRTFM, I would but 3 does not mean 3 years old. 3 is the value use to store the information of a 6 year old student

Comment: So, for example, does the value 12 represent a 15 year old?

Comment: @JR96 The two examples you used implied that the real age was the `Age` variable *plus* three. The code I offered _would_ give the results you wanted.  **ALSO** you may have corrected the "@" error but you have both `Age` and `age`. R is case sensitive, som one of those is probably wrong. You should do some testing of your code.

Comment: I just realized that would work. Thank you. I tried not to paste my code in here but would rather type it as that helps me remember as I study.

Comment: My only issue with the code below is that If I rerun that chunk of code, it fails since it is no longer a numeric argument 
It gives me an error:  "Error in data$txtAge + 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: “+” does not succeed with character values. It does in some languages but proposals to add that as a feature have not been accepted by RCore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps adding 3 and pasting " years old" will satisfy your needs?

```
 data$txtAge <- paste(data$Age, "years old")
```

There is no need for an iterative command. R's functions often iterate automagically. In this case the `paste` command is designed to return character results of the same length as the longest input argument but it "recycles" (repeats) the shorter argument. You would get a column of the same length as there were rows in the `data` object.

Answer (score 1):

Like IRTFM said, you have to add 3 and paste the `"years old"` string.
You're getting an error regarding non-numeric arguments to binary operators because you're trying to add a number to a character string.

So, let's be a little more explicit: you have to add 3 **first**, *and then* paste the `"years old"` string (you're doing it in the wrong order).